# Measuring AC voltage of the saturation photoelectric voltage

Tags: measurements, photoelectric-effect

im working on an experiment on the photoelectric effect in which i try to calculate the saturation current of different wave-lengths.
i do so by calculating the photoelectric Voltage on a resistor and then calculating the current. my light source is a mercury lamp which is flickering as expected from this kind of light source so i measure the photoelectric voltage by using the ac option on my multi-meter  - and here's the problem: when NO light source is on the reading is not 0 and not something close to 0 but a value well call V_max.
then i turn on the lamp and shine it through a 436nm filter the reading DROPS from said V_max.
now i turn the acceleration voltage between the anode and cathode to 5 volts and as expected, the reading is now bigger.
another thing is when i use the 514 filter - which according to the spectrum of the mercury lamp should yield a very small saturation current, i get the same V_max value i got when the light was off.
is this because of how ac measurements work?